# Parsing String to get required Data

Tags: shell, scripting, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse a line within a file that contains "ID" and a numeric entry. However, what the script below is doing is grabbing the "ID" numeric value plus everything after it. How can I just cut it down to "ID" + numeric value and nothing else?

Thanks in advance.

```
tail -n 1 events.log | sed 's/.*id=\([^)]\+\).*/\1/' > event_id.dat
```

Comment: paste examples of what is in and what out

Comment: if every match will contain "id=" then you don't really need to capture that part with your regex, right? Can't you just catch the numeric value and then add "id=" yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex string in brackets is `[^)]\+`, which means "all characters other than the end bracket".

If numerical digits is what you want to catch, you need to change that to `[0-9]\+`

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell what you're looking for without an example of input and expected output, but this might work most generally:

```
sed -e 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

That amounts to:

1. Look for lines include "id=" immediately followed by some numbers (`[0-9]*`), with any amount of anything before or after
2. Replace those lines with just the numbers (where `\1` references the part within parenthesis in the match expression)

Does that do what you want? If not, can you be more explicit with your input/output requirements?

Comment: I think you got it. Will try it and report back. Thanks for all the input, guys.